# Cors not working for Delete and Put in web api2

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have been struggling on the CORS issue since one week. I am writing web services using web api2. I created one controller(for basic crud operations) and hosted in server 192.168.0.213:8041/api/user_creation and i created another mvc5 application and hosted in the same server as http://192.168.0.213:8040/usercreation/Index. I have enabled cors using the below link.

```
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009ee3/implementation-of-cross-origin-request-in-Asp-Net-web-api-2/
```

I am using angularjs to fetch services as below. I able to get data from server and also I am able to push data to server. So my GET and POST verbs are working fine. Whenever i tried to update and delete i am facing issues and getting below error message.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)  http://192.168.0.213:8041/User_Creation/1020
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.213:8041/User_Creation/1020. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.213:8040' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

I am using angularjs to call web services as below.
For example for update,

```
this.update = function (sub) {
        var url = 'http://192.168.0.213:8041/User_Creation/' + sub.user_id;
        return $http({
            method: 'put',
            data: JSON.stringify(sub),
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

For delete,

```
this.deleteSubscriber = function (user_id) {
        var url = 'http://192.168.0.213:8041/User_Creation/' + user_id;
        return $http.delete(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
```

From Web Api I am receiving data in the form of json so i added below code in global.asx.
GlobalConfigGlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings

```
.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

This is my handler code in web.config

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

Below are request and response data.

```
   Request URL: http://192.168.0.213:8041/User_Creation/1021
   Request Method: DELETE
   Status Code: 405 / Method Not Allowed
 - Request Headers
   Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Content-Length: 0
   Host: 192.168.0.213:8041
   Referer: http://192.168.0.213:8040/usercreation/Index
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
 - Response Headers
   Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
   Content-Length: 1293
   Content-Type: text/html
   Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 08:34:30 GMT
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I am facing problem with PUT and Delete method. May i get some help on this? Can someone tell me where i am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: check `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in response header

Comment: Thank you. When i click on delete i will get some details. I posted above but i didnt understand what i am missing.

Comment: Could you show your Web API controller action?

Comment: I decorated controller as below.  [EnableCors(origins: "http://192.168.0.213:8040", headers: "Content-Type", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")] then below are my put and delete methods.  public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, Noor_Users users){  }   [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")] public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
        {   }.

Comment: In response header i can see only 
   Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE. So I do not have PUT and delete here? So this is causing problem here?

Comment: Are you able to successfully invoke the `DELETE` or `PUT` endpoints from Fiddler? I suspect that those verbs are not allowed for your web application.

Comment: i tried to delete in postman tp delete some data and i got 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs are not allowed on your web server and the issue you are having is not related to CORS at all. There are a couple of things you might want to checkout to ensure that those verbs are allowed in the first place. Before trying to make cross domain AJAX calls, make sure that you can make standard HTTP calls to your Web API and that it responds to those verbs.

So in your web.config you might have something like this:

```
add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Notice the absence of `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs here.

Also make sure that you have removed all `WebDAV` and `WebDAVModule` traces from your web.config as this might be interfering with your requests:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

Now that you can successfully call your Web API endpoints using the PUT and DELETE verbs using Postman or Fiddler you may go back to the javascript attempts.

Comment: Thank you. I will put what i have in handler.

Comment: Did you try adding the `<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>` line?

Comment: i just changed to verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" and now put started working fine and post not working and delete also.

Comment: Now all my verbs are working fine in IE but not in chrome.

Comment: Are the PUT and DELETE API endpoints working in when invoked from Postman/Fiddler?

Comment: No i am not using postman. Now in ie all my httpverbs are working but in chrome put and delete not working.

Comment: OK, as I said in my answer: you should first ensure that those verbs are supported by your web server/API. For this you need to send a plain HTTP request using a client different than a sandboxed browser. Postman/Fiddler are good tools for this purpose.

Comment: now i just checked in postman also. All httpverbs are working. Problem is with only chrome. before i did not try in ie.

Comment: OK, look if Chrome is making an OPTIONS request (also called pre-flight request in CORS) and how does your server respond to it? Also inspect the response headers returned by your server to this pre-flight request to ensure that your origin is there.

Comment: Okay now i am getting below error when i click on delete Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.